# Virgule et cætera

Tags: latin, ponctuation, abréviations

Quelle est la règle régissant l'usage de la virgule avant l'abréviation *etc.* ?

« On » m'avait dit il y a quelques années qu'*etc.* n'était pas (nécessairement) précédé d'une virgule ; or, la grammaire Grévisse indique que cette abréviation doit l'être si elle termine une énumération (page 45 de la 3ème édition). Est-ce uniquement une règle d'usage ou y a-t-il une raison grammaticale plus profonde ? À partir de quel moment estime-t-on qu'on est en présence d'une énumération (j'aurais tendance à penser qu'il faut *a minima* deux éléments) ? Quels peuvent être les exemples d'utilisation d'*etc.* sans énumération (et donc sans virgule) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oui, toujours une virgule avant. Cela semble logique puisque **etc.** est censé remplacer des éléments qui, s'ils avaient été énumérés, seraient précédés d'une virgule (et séparés par des virgules).
Pour l'énumération, Jean-Yves Dournon (Le Grand Livre de l'orthographe et de la grammaire) dit :

> Il faut au moins trois éléments dans un énumération pour ajouter
>   **etc.**

A ma connaissance, partout ailleurs la tendance est à 2 mots minimum.
Le sens de l'abréviation étant *et les autres choses*, il ne peut s'agir que d'une énumération. Dans la phrase de J.-Y. Dournon, certes, le mot **etc.** n'est pas précédé d'une virgule mais il n'est que cité, pas interprété. On peut trouver d'autres exemples de ce style...
NB: l'abréviation *etc.* peut être suivie d'une virgule si elle ne termine pas la phrase. Il est conseillé de la faire précéder par une espace insécable pour éviter qu'elle ne commence une ligne.

Comment: Au moins 3 éléments cités avant *«etc.»*, ou *«etc.»* doit-il remplacer au moins 3 éléments?

Comment: Je suis intuitivement assez d'accord avec le fait qu'*etc.* remplace des éléments énumérés, mais le fait que Grevisse spécifie qu'*etc.* est précédé d'une virgule dans le cas d'une énumération me donnait donc l'impression qu'on pouvait l'utiliser autrement... Merci pour la précision sur l'espace insécable, c'est un bon point auquel je n'avais pas pensé !

Comment: @MBR Tu viens d'utiliser **etc.** deux fois de suite autrement que dans une énumération et il n'est très justement pas précédé d'une virgule.

Comment: *Etc.* ne commence jamais une phrase. :)

Comment: @Feelew Je viens de modifier la réponse pour citer exactement la phrase de J.-Y. Dournon qui lève, à mon avis, l’ambiguïté. Merci.

Comment: Concernant *etc* sans virgule, me revient à l'esprit une chanson de S. Gainsbourg où on entend : **Aux armes etc.**. Cela me semble correct. De même : <<Il a commencé "Allons enfants" etc. et je me suis mis à pleurer...>> Ne me semble pas incorrect. Il y a juste une ambiguïté sur le sens de *etc* : se rapporte-t-il à la fin de la chanson ou en suggère-t-il une autre comme le chant des partisans. Merci de me donner votre avis.